# assert_select count expected exactly 2 elements matching "a[href="/"]", found 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to check how many links are routed to `root_path`.  My question is why is every route in my `_header.html.erb` file, when counted by `assert_select` is being doubled.  `root_path` is used in the page twice `<%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>` and `<li> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li>`, so why is it giving me `4`?  I'm new to rails and I'm following Michael Hartl's tutorial.

Here is my code for the integration test:

```
require 'test_helper'
class SiteLayoutTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest
    test "layout links" do
        get root_path
        assert_template 'static_pages/home'
        assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count:2
        assert_select "a[href=?]", help_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", about_path
        assert_select "a[href=?]", contact_path
    end
end
```

This is the partial code for my HTML file (`_header.html.erb`):

```
<header class="nav-bar navbar-fixed-top navbar-inverse" id="header">
    <div class="container">
        <%= link_to "sample app", root_path, id: "logo" %>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li> <%= link_to "Home", root_path %> </li>
                <li> <%= link_to "Help", help_path %> </li>
                <li> <%= link_to "Log in", "#" %> </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
</header>
```

When I run `bundle exec rake test`, it gives me 1 failure which is:

> FAIL["test_layout_links", SiteLayoutTest, 2016-06-15 20:11:58 +0800]
>   test_layout_links#SiteLayoutTest (1465992718.76s)
>
> Expected exactly 2 elements matching "a[href="/"]", found 4..
>
> Expected: 2
>
> Actual: 4
>
> test/integration/site_layout_test.rb:6:in `block in <class:SiteLayoutTest>'

Comment: `_header` is a partial, are you sure there aren't any links to `root` in the original view ?

Comment: you can also open your browser's console and type `$('a[href="/"]')` to see what root links you have

Comment: Yoo thanks niceman! I found out that i have 2 <%= render 'layouts/header'%> and that's causing the problem. Cool tip with the browser console :)

Comment: happy to help :), by the way post answer to your question and accept it

Answer (score 0):

you can change your test to be:

```
within(:css, "ul") do
      assert_select "a[href=?]", root_path, count:2
end
```

and it should work.  Here is a good resource to help with these type of issues: https://gist.github.com/zhengjia/428105

Answer (score 0):

Use this code in,

_header.html.erb:

<%= link_to "Home",   root_path %>

<%= link_to "Help",   help_path %>

_footer.html.erb:

<%= link_to "About",   about_path %>

<%= link_to "Contact", contact_path %>

Comment: Some additional explanations would probably be beneficial.